# Is it necessary reload eslint after remove ou add any rules?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I had to add two new rules `prefer-const` and `prefer-arrow-callback`, disable them.  So add inside  `rules`, but looks like the eslint stop to work, it does not format the document.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "rules": {
        "prefer-const": false,
        "prefer-arrow-callback":false

        }
}
```

Did I do it right or forget anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the way you've disabled the rules is wrong i.e. you should not use `false` but instead use `"off"`.

[Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files)

```
"rules": {
    "prefer-const": "off",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "off"
}
```